# Post Method from http Client in Qt5

Tags: c++, http, post, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

i have a LITTLE problem, i will make a client program for a connect http server in qt 5.1.0 i send a petition in json file by post method, the code of main methods involved in they work is next:

```
void HttpClient::sendJsonDocument(const QString typeId,const QString idClient)
{
QNetworkAccessManager *clientHttp=new QNetworkAccessManager();
clientHttp->clearAccessCache();
QUrl url("192.160.5.1:8383); //server adress
JsonManagment json;

QByteArray data;
data.clear();
data=("\r\n");
data.append(json.BuildJsonQuery(typeId,idClient));
data.append("\r\n");

QByteArray postDataSize = QByteArray::number(data.size());

QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Length",postDataSize);

SetHeaders(request, data);
QList <QByteArray> headers=request.rawHeaderList();
QList<QByteArray>::iterator i; 

QObject::connect(clientHttp,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinish(QNetworkReply *)));
QNetworkReply *serverReplaying=clientHttp->post(request,data);  
QEventLoop eloop;
QObject::connect(serverReplaying,SIGNAL(finished()),  &eloop,  SLOT(quit()),Qt::UniqueConnection); 
eloop.exec( QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents );
}
```

Well, the problem is when my program execute a post, aparently the post don't execute correctly because compared with a complement of firefox called poster, the content of the packets (and number of they are distinct), and ocasionally the server responds correctly, my program can't read the reply and resend the post petition even 3 times, and only get the error Clossed connection. The code of my slot replyFinished is next:

```
void HttpClient::replyFinish(QNetworkReply *serverReplayingy)
{
 qDebug()<<"one step more";
 if(serverReplayingy->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
 {
   qDebug()<<"error:"<<serverReplayingy->errorString();
   QByteArray responseData = serverReplayingy->readAll();
 }

 else
 { 
   JsonManagment jsonFile;
   QByteArray responseData = serverReplayingy->readAll();
   jsonFile.CreateJsonFile(responseData);
   QString qstr(responseData);
   qDebug()<<qstr;
 }
 return;
 }
```

I believe the server is correct (because he can respond to complement poster), and i will say two details, the first when i try check if the event loop is running, always give false, and second, the only way in i can get only 1 transmision and reception (1 petition) was when i cut the jsonfile, but i get error instantly from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to your object's lifecycles (i.e. if they are destroyed or alive). If the `QNetworkAccessManager` and/or the `HttpClient` are destroyed during the network request, the server response will vanish.

In your case, the `QNetworkAccessManager` is created in the method which sends the request to the server. So if the `HttpClient::sendJsonDocument();` method ends before the network request (which will likely happen), the `QNetworkAccessManager` will be destroyed before receiving the server response, the response will vanish and your `HttpClient` will not receive it. The best way to prevent it from happening is putting the `QNetworkAccessManager` in a global variable (or something like that).

Moreover be careful on how do you use your `HTTPClient`. If you use it in methods or functions like that :

```
void theFunction( /* the arguments*/ )
{
    // ...
    HttpClient client;
    // ...
    client.sendJsonDocument(typeID, clientID);
    // ...
}
```

the `HttpClient` will be destroyed at the end of the function. Just like the `QNetworkAccessManager` hereabove. So if the network request is not finished before the `HttpClient` destruction (which will likely happen too), the `HttpClient` will be destroyed and will not be able to receive the response. You will have to find a way to keep the `HttpClient` alive until the request is finished and its response is treated (in its `HttpClient::replyFinish(QNetworkReply *)` slot). Be careful if you use it in objects which might be destroyed befor the end of the whole request. **Everything have to stay alive or your request will vanish.**

Comment: thanks, i will follow your suggestions, for the design, but the  server finally was modified, and the systems starts to work good